# Remove "Add people" bar in slack

Tags: slack

Does anyone know how I can remove this huge bar suggesting me to add people to my workspace? This is so annoying and it takes half of the screen!!!

This is a workspace I only have for myself, so I don't want to add other people.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/comments/bo2lz2/remove_bring_your_team_into_slack_banner/), inviting an aliased version of your own email works to remove the banner. I invited a throwaway email of mine (which I don't plan on accepting) and the banner disappeared.